# How to delete sqlite_stat1 table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to delete the `sqlite_stat1` table from my database. I tried

```
DROP TABLE sqlite_stat1;
```

It says :

> sqlite_stat may not be dropped

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Internal tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#intschema) cannot simply be dropped.

However, the [ANALYZE documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) says:

> The content of the statistics tables can be queried using SELECT and can be changed using the DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE commands. The DROP TABLE command works on statistics tables as of SQLite version 3.7.9. (2011-11-01)

Answer (score 0):

The `{dbplyr}` has some wrapper functions, e.g. with [`copy_to`](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/copy_to.src_sql.html) you can set `analyze = FALSE`. If you are not an R user, you may find something useful in the source code of that function.